# "That heresies should arise, we have the prophesie of Christ..."

Tags: grammar, archaicisms, early-modern-english, that

> That heresies should arise, we have the prophesie of Christ; but that old ones should be abolished, we hold no prediction.

This is a quote from *Religio Medici* (1643) by Thomas Browne. It's quoted in *Contact* by Carl Sagan.

How does this sentence structure work? What does this mean? I'm particularly confused by the use of "that."

Comment: What a fine consensus

Comment: Early Modern English is not Old English.

Comment: You could think of "that" as meaning "whether".  (By the way, "prophesie" would in modern English be _prophecy_ , not _prophesy_)

Comment: @Brian: "* We have the prophecy of Christ whether heresies will arise" would be ungrammatical (and possibly heretical). *That* has its normal meaning.

Comment: Ah, right you are. I was only looking at the _second_ "that".

Comment: @BrianHitchcock But the second "that" also has the usual meaning. The text after the semi-colon is just an inversion of "We have no prediction that old heresies should be abolished."

Comment: I would point out that questions of this nature may be better suited for the [Biblical Hermeneutics SE site](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @HotLicks This question is mainly about grammar. It just happens that the example is religious in nature.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's inversion:

> That heresies should arise, we have the prophesie of Christ; but that
>   old ones should be abolished, we hold no prediction.

is a re-ordering of:

> We have the prophesie of Christ that heresies should arise; but we hold no prediction that old ones should be abolished.

Answer (score 11):

To paraphrase, I would say, "Christ predicted that there would be new heresies that would arise, so the author can be confidant that they will appear, but He said nothing about when old heresies would vanish, so the author makes no prediction about them."  This is in keeping with Browne's observation that supposedly-suppressed heresies seem to pop up elsewhere.

In each independent clause, there is a relative subordinate clause introduced by "that."  The first, "That heresies should arise," modifies "the prophesie of Christ" (or stands in apposition to it).  The second, "that old ones should be abolished," modifies "prediction."

Comment: I think your answer would benefit of more constraints on the quotation. Should the part `(...) so the author can be (...)` really be between the double quotes?

Comment: @Mindwin At least the way I read this answer, the part within the quotation marks is deadrat's paraphrase of the original quote. It seems accurate to me.

Answer (score 4):

Both sentences are versions of

> It was said **that** X would happen == **That** X would happen was said.

The verbal phrase "We have a prophesie that.."
is similar to "We have a law that..   "He made an announcement that...

So,without the inversion and with some "" (round what was foretold) ""   and (<< backshift) shown

> **1** We have the propehsie of Christ that ""  heresies should (<< shall) arise,"" ; **2**  but...  we hold no prediction that ""old ones
>   should (<< will) be abolished.""

Answer (score 4):

In both sentences, the order of the clauses has been inverted. This can be done to shift the focus of the sentence towards the clause that is moved forward.

In a standard construction, I could say:

> We have (a prophesy *that heresies will arise*); but we have no (prediction *that old ones will disappear*).

By simply moving the *italic* parts to the front we get:

> *That heresies will arise*, we have a prophesy; but *that old ones will disappear* we have no prediction.

Note that you might add an *of* after the verb in both sentences. It is common to add that to refer back to the clause that was moved to the front:

> *That heresies will arise*, we have a prophesy **of**; but *that old ones will disappear* we have no prediction **of**.

Comment: I think we find the *of* most often used like this:  We have a prophesy of heresies *arising*, but no prediction of old ones *disappearing*.

Comment: Can you substantiate your assertion about adding "of" in that way?  It seems decidedly unusual to me.